# Inno setup Classic ASP Enable Parent Paths

Tags: iis, asp-classic, inno-setup

I have created an installer for a classic asp website.
I can add the application to the IIS and set Application Pool, Friendly Name and Allow Scripts.
I would like to set "Enable Parent Paths" too.

Any idea? Is there any EnableParentPaths = true?

Here is somw code I used to add the website to IIS in case is needed:

```
if (IISOptionsPage.Values[1] <> '') then begin
  IISDefAppPool := IISOptionsPage.Values[1];
end else begin
  IISDefAppPool := ExpandConstant('{#IISDefaultAppPool}');  
end;

{ Create the main IIS COM Automation object }
try
  IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
except
  RaiseException('IIS is not installed?.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage );
end;

{ Connect to the IIS server }

WebSite := IIS.GetObject('IIsWebService', IISServerName + '/w3svc');
WebServer := WebSite.GetObject('IIsWebServer', IISServerNumber);
WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Root');

WebAppName := ExtractLastDir(ExpandConstant('{app}'));

{ (Re)create a virtual dir }

try
  WebRoot.Delete('IIsWebVirtualDir', WebAppName);
  WebRoot.SetInfo();
except

end;

VDir := WebRoot.Create('IIsWebVirtualDir', WebAppName); 
VDir.AccessRead := True;
VDir.AccessScript := True;
VDir.AppFriendlyName := WebAppName;
VDir.Path := ExpandConstant('{app}');

try
  VDir.AppPoolId := IISDefAppPool;
except
  MsgBox('AppPool not set.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

try
  VDir.AppCreate(True);
except
  MsgBox('App not created.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

try
  VDir.SetInfo();
except
  MsgBox('Info no set.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're looking for the [`AspEnableParentPaths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property of the [`IIsWebVirtualDir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524579%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object. Try to extend your script with the following line:

```
VDir.AspEnableParentPaths := True;
```